# Localization not works

Tags: android, localization

I write android app and make localization on some languages, English is default.

[image: localizations]

Than, I build APK, downloaded app to my phone & checked localizations. When I change my system language to one from the list above, my app auto switch to this language.

Than, I build ABB & released my app to Android Play Market. After release, I updated it and tried to check localizations switchig system language. Wherein, my location is Russia. When my system language is Russian, app on Russian. When system language is any other from list above (French, German, Chinese etc.), app language is English.

Have any idea, what wrong & how to fix it?

Comment: It may take some time for play services to trigger the download. Have you tried if it works if you setup additional languages as 2nd, 3rd language and so on in system settings?

Comment: Certainly, I check localization after update from Play Market. I use MIUI OS wrapper & have only one language on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, app downloads only with locale as language setup on your device when you install app. If you switch system language and open Play Market, new locale downloads on your device.